# Interfacing a RS232 printer through USB adaptor

Tags: serial-port, usb

I have a receipt printer that uses a RS232 port. I am thinking of using a USB adaptor to connect it to my PC and then talk/send data to it through my application. My question is, would this still work with an adaptor? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If  you use Linux, then most probably yes. Most, if not all serial to USB converters are supported, and present a standard serial port to the application, typically called `/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar.

On Windows, I cannot confirm - I don't use Windows. I seem to recall that those adapters, in some cases, but not always, appear as a COMn: port. In this case it should work too. Not always the emulation of the COM port is correct though.